# Facebook graph api not returning some fields for a root node endpoint

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Earlier for the endpoint "Conversation" we use to receive many for fields-profileImageURL, isAuthorVerfied etc. Those fields are not getting returned anymore in graph api version 2.8/2.9. Also old documentation for <2.8 the feilds are not getting displayed in docuemnt- https://developers.facebook.com/.../ref.../v2.8/conversation.
Anybody else facing the same issue?

Comment: do you know about the fields parameter? check it out in the docs if not. it´s called "declarative fields".

Comment: Did you even read the problem? I have attached the url of the page which shows all the fields. But it doesn't contains the profileImageURL field. Which it was having in older versions.

Comment: my bad, so it´s about a field that does not exist anymore in newer versions according to the docs. did you check out the changelog? if it does not exist anymore, then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Yeah the field definitely doesn't exists any more in newer versions. It used to exist in older versions. But when i am changing to the documentation of older version(by changing the graph api version in the upper right corner drop down) it is not populating the fields that used to exist in older version, in the given url.                                                                                                                 Also in the graph api application if i select older version and send the request with all fields allowed in older version, it is not giving back those fields.